# Formulario, preenchido com a mesma informação, do segundo ID

Tags: php, html5, phpmyadmin

Olá estou com um problema, quando clico no botão visualizar que chama a tela que ira preencher o formulário o mesmo vem preenchido com a mesma informação do segundo ID mesmo clicando na primeira informação da tela e ocorre o erro, poderiam me dar uma direção?

Veja que na imagem abaixo eu clico no primeiro botao com o codigo ficha 41
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mais quando a tela do formulario abre ela traz as informações do codigo ficha 42, e apresenta um erro veja.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Codigo da pagina de movimentacoesMusica.php

```html
<?php
 session_start();
 $connect = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','') or die('Erro ao conectar ao banco de dados');
    $db = mysqli_select_db($connect,'db_uberlandia');
  // A sessão precisa ser iniciada em cada página diferente
  if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();
    
  // Verifica se não há a variável da sessão que identifica o usuário
  if (!isset($_SESSION['UsuarioID'])) {
      // Destrói a sessão por segurança
      session_destroy();
      // Redireciona o visitante de volta pro login
      header("Location: index.php"); exit;
  }
  
  $codUsuario = $_SESSION['UsuarioID'];

  
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="Página Administrativa">
    <meta name="author" content="Cesar">
    <link rel="icon" href="imagens/favicon.ico">
 

    <title>Movimentação Musica</title>
    <link href="src/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="src/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="src/css/theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="src/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>
 
 <!--adicionado depois-->
 
 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/css/modificadonovo.css">
 

  
 
 <!--script adicionado depois-->
 
 
  </head>

  <body role="document">
  
  
  <div id="responsive-admin-menu">
 <div id="responsive-menu">
  <div class="menuicon">≡</div>
 </div>
 
 <div id="logo"></div>

 <!--Menu-->
 <div id="menu">
   <a href="menuMusica.php"><button type='button' class='btn btn-md btn-info'>Voltar</button></a>
   
  
 </div>
 <!--Menu-->
      </br>
 

</div>
  
 
        <div class="h1">
  <center>
  <h2>Movimentações Ficha Cadastral Musica</h2>
  </center>
        </div>
 <?php
  $result_usuario = "SELECT * FROM ficha_Cadastral_Musica where (`CodUsuario` = '".$codUsuario."')";
  $resultado_usuario = mysqli_query($connect, $result_usuario);
 ?> 
    <div class="container theme-showcase" role="main">      
      <div class="page-header">
        <h1>Lista de Fichas Inseridas no Sistema</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <table class="table" >
            <thead>
              <tr>
       <th>CODIGO FICHA</th>
                <th>IEQ BAIRRO</th>
    <th>PASTOR</th>
    <th>LIDER</th>
     <th>Ações</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
    <?php 
     while($row_usuario = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_usuario)){
      echo "<tr>";
          echo "<td>".$row_usuario['codFichaMusica']."</td>";
       echo "<td>".$row_usuario['ieqbairro']."</td>";
       echo "<td>".$row_usuario['pastor']."</td>";
       echo "<td>".$row_usuario['lider']."</td>";
       "</td>";
       ?>
       <td>
             
               <a href='editarFichaCadastralMusica.php?CodUsuario=<?php echo $row_usuario['CodUsuario']?><?php
         $row_usuario['CodUsuario']; ?>?codFicha=<?php echo $row_usuario['codFichaMusica']?><?php
            $row_usuario['codFichaMusica']; ?>?'><button 
               type='button'  class='btn btn-sm btn-warning'>Visualizar & Editar</button></a>
         
         <a href='excluirFichaCadastralMusica.php?CodUsuario=<?php echo $row_usuario['CodUsuario']?><?php
         $row_usuario['CodUsuario']; ?>'><button 
         type='button' class='btn btn-sm btn-danger'>Excluir</button></a>
         
                <?php
      echo "</tr>";
     }
    ?>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
  </div>
    </div> <!-- /container -->


    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/docs.min.js"></script>
    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

codigo da pagina de Editar, onde o formulario é preenchido.

editarFichaCadastralMusica.php

```html
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','');
$db = mysqli_select_db($connect,'db_uberlandia');

  $gid = $_GET['CodUsuario'];
  $codFicha = $_GET['codFichaMusica'];
 $q = ("SELECT * FROM ficha_Cadastral_Musica WHERE CodUsuario='".$gid."' & codFichaMusica ='".$codFicha."'");

 $resultado_usuario = mysqli_query ($connect, $q);
 $row_usuario = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_usuario);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Editar Ficha Cadastral Musica</title>
  
  
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'>

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/css/style1.css">
   
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/css/modificado.css">
   
     
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,100,300,500,700,900'>
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700'>
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'>


<style>
label {
  display: block;
  color: #0e0572;
}

::placeholder ,select, option { /* Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari 10.1+ */
  color: #0e0572;
  font-weight: bold;
  
}

::form-group  { /* Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari 10.1+ */
  color: #0e0572;
  font-weight: bold;
  
}

.floatBlock {
  margin: 0 1.81em 0 0;
}

.labelish {
 color:#0e0572;
 margin: 0;
 font-weight: bold;
}

.paymentOptions {
 border: none;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 justify-content: flex-start;
 break-before: always;
 margin: 0 0 3em 0;
}

#purchaseOrder {
 margin: 0 0 2em 0;
}

#nomeministeriocarreira{

 height: 135px;


}



</style>

<script>

 function mascara(t, mask){
 var i = t.value.length;
 var saida = mask.substring(1,0);
 var texto = mask.substring(i)
 if (texto.substring(0,1) != saida){
 t.value += texto.substring(0,1);
 }
 }
 </script>

  
</head>

<body>

  <div id="responsive-admin-menu">
 <div id="responsive-menu">
  <div class="menuicon">≡</div>
 </div>
 
 <div id="logo"></div>

 <!--Menu-->
 <div id="menu">
  <a href="menuMusica.php" title=""><i class="icon-dashboard"></i><span>Home</span></a>
   <a href="fichaCadastralMusica.html" title="Pages"><i class="icon-fixed-width icon-pencil"></i><span> Ficha Cadastral</span></a>
   <a href="relatoriomensal1regiaomusica.html" title="Pages"><i class="icon-file-alt"></i><span> Relatório Mensal</span></a>
   <a href="movimentacoesMusica.php" title="Pages"><i class="icon-fixed-width icon-book"></i><span> Movimentações Ficha &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Cadastral</span></a>
   <a href="movimentacoes1regiaomusicarelatorio.php" title="Pages"><i class="icon-fixed-width icon-book"></i><span> Movimentações &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Relatório</span></a>
   <a href="logout.php" title="Pages"><i class="icon-fixed-width icon-cogs"></i><span> Sair</span></a>
   
  
 </div>
 <!--Menu-->


</div>

<div id="content-wrapper">

 
 <form method="POST" action="alteracaoFichaCadastralMusica.php">
     <center>
  <h1>Editar Ficha Cadastral Musica</h1>
  </center>
     
    <div class="contentform">
     <div id="sendmessage"> Your message has been sent successfully. Thank you. </div>
  
  <input type="hidden" name="CodUsuario" value="<?php echo $row_usuario['CodUsuario']; ?>">
  <input type="hidden" name="codFicha" value="<?php echo $row_usuario['codFichaMusica']; ?>">
  
   <div class="form-group">
       <p class="labelish">I.E.Q Bairro:</p>
    <span class="icon-case"><i class="fa fa-bars custom"></i></span>
    <font color="#6b0202"><input type="text"  name="ieqbairro" id="ieqbairro"  data-rule="required" style="text-transform: uppercase;"  placeholder="Não há registro no banco" value="<?php echo $row_usuario['ieqbairro']; ?>"></font>
         </div>
   
   <div class="form-group">
        <p class="labelish">Pastor:</p>
    <span class="icon-case"><i class="fa fa-bars custom"></i></span>
    <input type="text" name="pastor" id="pastor" data-rule="required"  style="text-transform: uppercase;" placeholder="Não há registro no banco" value="<?php echo $row_usuario['pastor']; ?>">
         </div>
   
   
    <div class="form-group">
     <p class="labelish">Líder:</p>
    <span class="icon-case"><i class="fa fa-bars custom"></i></span>
    <input type="text" name="lider" id="lider" style="text-transform: uppercase;" data-rule="required" placeholder="Não há registro no banco" value="<?php echo $row_usuario['lider']; ?>">
         </div>
   
   <div class="form-group">
     <p class="labelish">Células Ativas:</p>
     <span class="icon-case"><i class="fa fa-bars custom"></i></span>
            <input type="text" name="celulasativas" id="celulasativas" style="text-transform: uppercase;" data-rule="required"placeholder="Não há registro no banco" value="<?php echo $row_usuario['celulaAtivas']; ?>">

         </div> 
   
   <div class="form-group">
        <p class="labelish">Participantes Celulas Quantidade:</p>
     <span class="icon-case"><i class="fa fa-bars custom"></i></span>
    <input type="number" name="participantescelulas" id="participantescelulas"  data-rule="required" style="text-transform: uppercase;" placeholder="Não há registro no banco" value="<?php echo $row_usuario['participantescelulas']; ?>">
         </div> 
   
   <div class="form-group">
         <p class="labelish">Quantidade Reuniões:</p>
     <span class="icon-case"><i class="fa fa-bars custom"></i></span>
    <input type="number" name="quantidadereunioes" id="quantidadereunioes" data-rule="required" style="text-transform: uppercase;"  placeholder="Não há registro no banco" value="<?php echo $row_usuario['quantidadereunioes']; ?>">
         </div> 
   
   <div class="form-group">
        <p class="labelish">Quantidade Ensaios Mensais:</p>
     <span class="icon-case"><i class="fa fa-bars custom"></i></span>
    <input type="number" name="quantidaensamensal" id="quantidaensamensal" data-rule="required"  style="text-transform: uppercase;" placeholder="Não há registro no banco" value="<?php echo $row_usuario['quantidaensamensal']; ?>">
         </div>

           <div class="form-group">
     <p class="labelish">Dia do Ensaio:</p>
   <!-- <span class="icon-case"><i class="fa fa-bookmark custom"></i></span>-->
    <!--<input type="text" name="diaensaio" id="diaensaio" style="text-transform: uppercase;"  placeholder="Dia do Ensaio"/>-->
     <select class="form-control" name="diaensaio" id="diaensaio">
                       <option><?php echo $row_usuario['diaensaio']; ?></option>
                       <option>SEGUNDA</option>
                       <option>TERÇA</option>
        <option>QUARTA</option>
        <option>QUINTA</option>
        <option>SEXTA</option>
        <option>SABADO</option>
        <option>DOMINGO</option>
              </select>
          </div>   
        
  <div class="form-group">
      <p class="labelish">Hora do Ensaio:</p>
   <span class="icon-case"><i class="fa fa-bars custom"></i></span>
       <input type="text" name="horaensaio" id="horaensaio" onkeypress="mascara(this,'--:--')" maxlength="5" style="text-transform: uppercase;"  placeholder="Não há registro no banco" value="<?php echo $row_usuario['horaensaio']; ?>">
         </div>    
         
    <div class="form-group">
       <p class="labelish">Total de Membros do Departamento:</p>
    <span class="icon-case"><i class="fa fa-bars custom"></i></span>
    <input type="number" name="totalmembrosdepartamento" id="totalmembrosdepartamento"  placeholder="Não há registro no banco" style="text-transform: uppercase;"  value="<?php echo $row_usuario['totalmenbrosminis']; ?>">
         </div>
           
     <div class="form-group">
       <p class="labelish">Vocal:(qtos):</p>
    <span class="icon-case"><i class="fa fa-bars custom"></i></span>
    <input type="number" name="vocal" id="vocal" data-rule="required" style="text-transform: uppercase;"  pplaceholder="Não há registro no banco" value="<?php echo $row_usuario['vocalquant']; ?>">
         </div>
   
   
   
     <div class="form-group">
     <p class="labelish">Mulheres: Contralto(qtas):</p>
    <span class="icon-case"><i class="fa fa-bars custom"></i></span>
    <input type="number" name="mulhercontralto" id="mulhercontralto" data-rule="required" onkeypress="mascaraData(this)" style="text-transform: uppercase;" placeholder="Não há registro no banco"
    value="<?php echo $row_usuario['mulhercontralto']; ?>">
         </div>
   
   <div class="form-group">
       <p class="labelish">Mezzo-soprano(qtas):</p>
    <span class="icon-case"><i class="fa fa-bars custom"></i></span>
    <input type="number" name="mezzosoprano" id="mezzosoprano"  data-rule="required" style="text-transform: uppercase;" placeholder="Não há registro no banco" value="<?php echo $row_usuario['mulhermezzosoprano']; ?>">
         </div>
   
   
    <div class="form-group">
       <p class="labelish">Soprano(qtas):</p>
    <span class="icon-case"><i class="fa fa-bars custom"></i></span>
    <input type="number" name="soprano" id="soprano" data-rule="required" style="text-transform: uppercase;" placeholder="Não há registro no banco" value="<?php echo $row_usuario['mulhersoprano']; ?>">
         </div>
  
   
   <div class="form-group">
       <p class="labelish">Homens: Baixo(qtos):</p>
    <span class="icon-case"><i class="fa fa-bars custom"></i></span>
    <input type="number" name="homensbaixo" id="homensbaixo" data-rule="required" style="text-transform: uppercase;"  placeholder="Não há registro no banco" value="<?php echo $row_usuario['homensbaixo']; ?>">
         </div>
   
    <div class="form-group">
       <p class="labelish">Barítono(qtos):</p>
    <span class="icon-case"><i class="fa fa-bars custom"></i></span>
    <input type="number" name="baritono" id="baritono" data-rule="required" style="text-transform: uppercase;" placeholder="Não há registro no banco" value="<?php echo $row_usuario['homensbaritono']; ?>">
         </div>
   
   
    <div class="form-group">
       <p class="labelish">Tenor(qtos):</p>
    <span class="icon-case"><i class="fa fa-bars custom"></i></span>
    <input type="number" name="tenor" id="tenor" data-rule="required" style="text-transform: uppercase;" placeholder="Não há registro no banco" value="<?php echo $row_usuario['homenstenor']; ?>">
         </div>
   
    <div class="form-group">
       <p class="labelish">Guitarrista:(qtos):</p>
    <span class="icon-case"><i class="fa fa-bars custom"></i></span>
    <input type="number" name="guitarrista" id="guitarrista" data-rule="required" style="text-transform: uppercase;"  placeholder="Não há registro no banco" value="<?php echo $row_usuario['guitarraqtd']; ?>">
         </div>
   
   
    <div class="form-group">
      <p class="labelish">Bateristas:(qtos):</p>
    <span class="icon-case"><i class="fa fa-bars custom"></i></span>
    <input type="number" name="bateristas" id="bateristas" data-rule="required" style="text-transform: uppercase;"  placeholder="Não há registro no banco" value="<?php echo $row_usuario['bateristaqtd']; ?>">
         </div>
   
   
    <div class="form-group">
       <p class="labelish">Tecladista:(qtos):</p>
    <span class="icon-case"><i class="fa fa-bars custom"></i></span>
    <input type="number" name="tecladistas" id="tecladistas" data-rule="required" style="text-transform: uppercase;"  placeholder="Não há registro no banco" value="<?php echo $row_usuario['tecladistaqtd']; ?>">
         </div>
   
   
    <div class="form-group">
        <p class="labelish">Violão(qtos):</p>
    <span class="icon-case"><i class="fa fa-bars custom"></i></span>
    <input type="number" name="violao" id="violao" data-rule="required" style="text-transform: uppercase;" placeholder="Não há registro no banco" value="<?php echo $row_usuario['violaoqtd']; ?>">
         </div>
   
    <div class="form-group">
      <p class="labelish">Baixistas(qtos:</p>
    <span class="icon-case"><i class="fa fa-bars custom"></i></span>
    <input type="number" name="baixistas" id="baixistas" data-rule="required" style="text-transform: uppercase;"  placeholder="Não há registro no banco" value="<?php echo $row_usuario['baixoqtd']; ?>">
         </div>
   
   <div class="form-group">
        <p class="labelish">Meia Lua(qtos):</p>
    <span class="icon-case"><i class="fa fa-bars custom"></i></span>
    <input type="number" name="meialua" id="meialua" data-rule="required" style="text-transform: uppercase;"  placeholder="Não há registro no banco" value="<?php echo $row_usuario['meialuaqtd']; ?>">
         </div>
  
  <div class="form-group">
       <p class="labelish">Cajon(qtos):</p>
    <span class="icon-case"><i class="fa fa-bars custom"></i></span>
    <input type="number" name="cajon" id="cajon" data-rule="required" style="text-transform: uppercase;"  placeholder="Não há registro no banco" value="<?php echo $row_usuario['cajonqtd']; ?>">
         </div>
  
  
  <div class="form-group">
       <p class="labelish">Outros:</p>
    <span class="icon-case"><i class="fa fa-bars custom"></i></span>
    <input type="text" name="outros" id="outros" data-rule="required" style="text-transform: uppercase;"  placeholder="Não há registro no banco" value="<?php echo $row_usuario['outros']; ?>">
         </div>
  
  <div class="form-group">
      <p class="labelish">Ministério de carreira:</p>
           <input type="text" name="ministeriocarreira" id="ministeriocarreira" data-rule="required" style="text-transform: uppercase;" placeholder="Não há registro no banco"  value="<?php echo $row_usuario['ministeriodecarreira']; ?>">
         </div>
   
   <div class="form-group">
       <p class="labelish">Descrição (Nome dos ministérios de carreira):</p>
    <span class="icon-case"><i class="fa fa-bars custom"></i></span>
    <input type ="text" rows="5" name="nomeministeriocarreira" id="nomeministeriocarreira" data-rule="required" style="text-transform: uppercase;" placeholder="Não há registro no banco"
    value="<?php echo $row_usuario['descrinomemstcarreira']; ?>">
         </div>
  
  <p id="demo"></p>
   
  
   
   <div class="form-group">
   <center><button type="submit" class="btn-lg btn-success" onclick="myFunction()">Alterar & Salvar</button>
         </div> 
   
 </div>

</form> 
  
 

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Na url você está passando `CodFicha` ao invés de `CodFichaMusica`. Faz essa troca pra ver se dá certo.

Comment: @smourao deu certo obrigado!